# why in the ember the action is listed as data-ember-action="824"?

Tags: ember.js

in the code i have written the name of the action where call should be forwarded. In place of name of the action number is coming why ?

please help me to understand this ,,,

Regards,
Trilok.

Answer (score 1):

This is an internal property created by the html/handle-bars compiler. The number can be different each time so you shouldn't do anything with those values, like querying with jQuery etc.

Comment: So a part from seeing in the code that which action is called is there any other way to know that which action is called ?

Comment: You mean in developer tools? I dont see any simple way, but you can just console log in actions: in your controllers/routes/etc.

Comment: hmm this seems only way just log every thing out !

Comment: But why do you need this? Isn't this better just to read the docs and see how the {{action}} helper works? Can you provide some code snippet were you would need it?